# AVD in eclipse(Juno) won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've installed Eclipse, then the android-sdk-windows v21 (which is in `C:\eclipse\android-sdk-windows`). The two icons SDK manager and AVD manager appear on menu bar.

Now, when I click on the AVD icon I get a brief flash of a cmd, then nothing. Tried again and got this message

```
[2012-11-29 15:55:26 - SDK Manager] 
    Error parsing C:\Users\adam\.android\devices.xml, backing up to 
        C:\Users\adam\.android\devices.xml.old
```

I've also tried running it direct from the android folder, same result. I've deleted all eclipse, android etc, and re-installed). I've looked on the net, but I have not come across this problem. Any insight will be very welcome. I'm running win7, Eclipse-Juno. Cdlt.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have changed the content of devices.xml file. The solution for me was to replace the file devices.xml from the original SDK file .